# How to maintain a client EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I am looking at creating an Amazon Machine Image (AMI) to sell on Amazon AWS Market Place.

I have a general understanding of how to create and sell an AMI instance but I am unsure of the best way to provide maintain/support for a client EC2 instance.

I plan to create a AMI using Amazon Linux which runs our Java software application.

Question:
What is the best way to provide updates and support to a customer who has bought our AMI instance?

Comment: How about setting up your own Apt-get repository and adding that to the AMI's sources.list before making an AMI (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine). See here on setting up own repository: http://blog.jonliv.es/2011/04/26/creating-your-own-signed-apt-repository-and-debian-packages/

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will look into the Apt-get repo.